# Swift - trigger method in subclass when superclass property changes

Tags: swift, subclass, superclass, observers

I have three a superclass with 2 subclasses as follows:

```
class BaseLookupViewController {
}

class RetrieveCompletedordersViewController: BaseLookupViewController {
}

class LoginViewController: BaseLookupViewController {
}
```

In BaseLookupViewController I have a property 'deviceOnline':

```
internal var deviceConnected = true
```

This is set using an observer from a different class:

```
override public func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    stackView.customPadding(Constants.stackViewPadding, after: submitButton)
    addConectivityObserver()
}


// MARK: - Configuration

private func addConectivityObserver() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(connectivityChanged(notification:)), name: .connectivityStatusChanged, object: nil)
}

@objc private func connectivityChanged(notification: Notification) {
    if notification.object as? ConnectionService.ConnectionStatus == .connected {
        deviceConnected = true
    } else {
        deviceConnected = false
    }
}
```

When the bool is set, I need to trigger specific methods in each of the subclasses. For example, in RetrieveCompletedordersViewController I need trigger the following:

```
    if deviceConnected {
        self.tabBarItem.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "retrieve_completed")
        self.errorLabel?.isHidden = true
    } else {
        self.tabBarItem.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "retrieve_offline")
        self.errorLabel?.isHidden = false
    }
```

And a similar method but obviously on a different property in the other subclass. I really want to avoid adding a property observer to each of the subclasses as it seems unnecessary. The cleanest way seems to be somehow to set the subclasses' properties within the willSet method of 'deviceConnected' but as these classes are not singletons BaseLookupViewController. What is the cleanest way to achieve this without repetitive code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, because the methods to call are type dependent there should be an object responsible for performing said calls, the most straightforward and logical way to do it that I can see is making them manage themselves, which means that each subclass should handle calling whatever methods need to be called when the `deviceConnected` property is changed.

You can override said property on each subclass and add the method calling code in a `didSet`, you won't loose any capability of the superclass because it's still a stored property defined by its superclass, which means, if you were to upcast to the superclass you would still have access to that property as the override doesn't invalidate the original declaration.

Something like this:

```
class RetrieveCompletedordersViewController: BaseLookupViewController {

    override var deviceConnected: Bool {
        didSet {
            if deviceConnected {
                tabBarItem.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "retrieve_completed")
                errorLabel?.isHidden = true
            } else {
                tabBarItem.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "retrieve_offline")
                errorLabel?.isHidden = false
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In order for the subclass specific `didSet` to be called you must set the property value on the subclass instance itself, if you upcast and set a value on the superclass it won't be executed, which is effectively what you are doing by calling a #selector directly in the superclass. To solve this add a notification observer with a closure instead, this will capture the subclass as self and properly execute the `didSet`:

```
var notificationObservers: Array<NSObjectProtocol> = []

override public func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    stackView.customPadding(Constants.stackViewPadding, after: submitButton)
    notificationObservers.append(
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                forName: .connectivityStatusChanged,
                object: nil,
                queue: .main,
                using: { [weak self] (notification) in
                           if notification.object as? ConnectionService.ConnectionStatus == .connected {
                               self?.deviceConnected = true
                           } else {
                               self?.deviceConnected = false
           })
    )
}
```

Remember to always remove the observer from Notification Center when no longer using the notification, such as when the object is de-initialized, I like to do this with an array to handle clean up:

```
deinit {
        // Perform cleanup of any Apple Notification Center notifications to which we may have registered
        notificationObservers.forEach { (observer) in
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply on this, I definitely like this method. However, my override var didSet is not being called strangely enough when the property is being set in the superclass :/

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong, by using a selector you do not capture self, check updated answer and try it :)

Comment: hmmm strange one, still not hitting it. I'm gonna have a play around and see if I can figure it out. Thanks a lot for the input